# Why does consul services register do nothing?

Tags: consul

I have created a simple JSON service definition file and am attempting to register it as a service in the local consul agent on the server:

```
/ $ consul services register /tmp/foo.service
```

However, nothing happens - I don't see the service or its health check in the HTTP API - and there is no output (but the exit code is 0), and when I do

```
/ $ consul monitor -log-level debug
```

I don't see any API calls being made that correspond to this register command.

Answer (score 0):

The filename needs to have extension `.json`, otherwise it will silently be ignored. The result is that the command creates no services - which is not considered to be an error.

So this works:

```
mv /tmp/foo.service /tmp/foo.json       # Rename file to have correct file extension
consul services register /tmp/foo.json
```

and the second command outputs:

```
Registered service: test
```